# Illegal instruction on the arm

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
m1 = tf.constant([[3, 3]])
print(m1)
m2 = tf.constant([[2], [3]])
print(m2)
product = tf.matmul(m1, m2)
sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(product)
print(result)
sess.close()
```

when running on arm, the following problems appear:

0

Illegal instruction

In other words, The "sess.run (train)" error is reported, and "the sess.run() "function is on arm. I have tested that the function can run, that is, the gradient descent can not run normally; There is the problem of illegal instruction; CPU：

```
root@EmbedSky-Board:/xzy/mix# lscpu
Architecture:          armv7l
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
Model name:            ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
CPU max MHz:           996.0000
CPU min MHz:           792.0000
root@EmbedSky-Board:/xzy/mix# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 6.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10
```

The ARM is TQIMX6Q that is NXP i.MX6Q Cortex-A9 4x1GHz from TianQian,Tensorflow from https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/, the error that illegal instruction may be caused by the difference between arm instruction set and x86 instruction set, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: How does this differ from [your old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411608/illegal-instruction-on-the-arm-linux)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a related problem with using TensorFlow on a M1 Mac. Solution is to use a universal arm version of TF.

Instructions to installing those versions are found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup

EDIT: `apt-get update && apt-get install tensorflow-model-server-universal` should work